# Is it possible to create Form in django that lets you change or add directly in the database?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, formset

Is it possible to create a form that modifies when information is already find in the database or so adds information if there is nothing in the database ?

So I have a template that allows me to display the value if there is one in the base given to the fields or answer then display a blank field for the answer.

My template for my formset :

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }} {% csrf_token %}
    <table>

      <!-- <br>{{ formset.as_table }}<br> -->

      {% for question in questions %}<hr>

    <label for="question">{{ question }} [{{ question.id }}]</label>  
    <input type="hidden" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-question" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-question" value="{{ question.id }}"/>
 </p>
{% if question.reply_set.all %}
  {% for reply in question.reply_set.all %}
    <p>
    <label for="answer">Réponse :</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" value="{{ reply.answer }}"/>
    </p>
  {% endfor %}  
{% else %}
    <p>
    <label for="answer">Réponse :</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-answer" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-answer" placeholder="answer here"/>
    </p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
       <br><br><br><hr> <br><br><br>
    </table><br>
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
    <a href="../../baseVisite/" class="btn btn-success">Retour</a></center>
  </form>
```

My problem is that I get a good add when there is nothing in the database but when I have Data if I change its value this create another answer as I would like it replaced the answer with the new!

> My views.py

```
def access(request, instance):
    questions = Question.objects.filter(page=instance)
    pages = Page.objects.all()
    numPages = Page.objects.get(pk=instance)
    length_questions = len(questions)
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    instance = {'instance':instance}
    ReplyFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Reply, form=ReplyForm, extra=length_questions)
    ReplyFormSet.form = staticmethod(curry(ReplyForm, instance=numPages))
    if logged_user:
        if request.method == 'POST':  
            formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if formset.is_valid():
                new_instances = formset.save(commit=False)
                for new_instance in new_instances:
                    new_instance.user = logged_user
                    new_instance.save()
                return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
         'formset': formset,
         'questions':questions,
         'logged_user':logged_user,
         'numPages' : numPages
         })
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "L'ajout à bien été effectué !")
                return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
         'formset': formset,
         'questions':questions,
         'logged_user':logged_user,
         'numPages' : numPages
         })
        else:
            formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset = Reply.objects.none())
        return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
         'formset': formset,
         'questions':questions,
         'logged_user':logged_user,
         'numPages' : numPages
         })
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

My model allows me to answer several questions at the same time ..

> My models.py

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    page = models.ManyToManyField(Page)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.label

class Reply(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

**How can I change the values instead adding in once again when there is already in the database?**

> Edit : screenshot of the problem
>   This saves 2 other lines more when I submit ..

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you can edit current replies using your current approach by adding a hidden `id` field in your reply forms like

```
{% for reply in question.reply_set.all %}
    <p>
    <label for="answer">Réponse :</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" value="{{ reply.answer }}"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-id" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-id" value="{{ reply.id }}"/>
    </p>
  {% endfor %}
```

this will tell your `ReplyFormset` that these records already exist, so instead of creating new records, edit existing records.

Yet, most of the work you are doing manually, can be done using Django's built in functionality, i.e. Django Formsets (which you are using but not using right). [Django Inline Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) are the Django way of doing it.

Comment: I just tested your code but it always make me the same problem ... This re-registers other values i can share you a screen shot

Comment: for now it create me a line, but its does not change the already present lines: 3

Answer (score 4):

Django form will create a new entry in db if you are calling a `form` without an instance.

```
form = MyForm()
```

On the contrary, if you want to update the existing entry in tha db pass the `instance` to the `form`.

```
form = MyForm(instance=myinstance)
```